# Probelm Conect Laravel to filrebase

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygnY6.jpg)
i need conect laravel to firbase is see this error
i see line over ServiceAccount what this problem

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Kreait\Firebase;
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

class FirebaseController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/firebaseKey.json');
        $firebase = (new Factory)
            ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
            ->create();
        $db = $firebase->getDatabase();
        $reference = $db->getReference('posts');
        $snapshot = $reference->getSnapshot();
        $value = $snapshot->getValue();
        dd($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: what error are you referring to?

Comment: please click in this link 

enter image description here

Comment: what is the error you got exactly? what error message is displaying

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygnY6.jpg  i see line over ServiceAccount please open this link to open image